# Should we make the crash-investigation tag a synonym for accident-investigation?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Today, we have these two tags:

- [accident-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation) - [37 questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation)
- [crash-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash-investigation) - [16 questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash-investigation)

I propose that we make [crash-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash-investigation) a synonym for [accident-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation). "Accident investigation" is a more professional, accurate term that covers 'crashes' anyway, but having the synonym is probably useful for people who think of the more informal word first (maybe we should [blame National Geographic](http://www.natgeotv.com/uk/shows/natgeo/air-crash-investigation) for that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added the synonym. [crash-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash-investigation) now maps to [accident-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation).

Answer (score 15):

Personally, I would say yes. I don't see any benefit on having the two separate tags.

Comment: I can't phrase it any better!